# Different positioning in Firefox, Internet Explorer and Safari?

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser, positioning, element

I believe this question has been asked a lot of times, and I have managed to overcome this problem before whenever it occurred. Just now, I feel stuck with it and can't find a proper solution to make it work in all browsers: it does work properly only in Firefox, while in IE and Safari its elements are somehow apart from each other. You can see the result here:
http://img813.imageshack.us/img813/8393/firefox.png
http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/8041/10990669.png

This is the code I use:
http://pastebin.com/n6KEjazp

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: In your global selector you have padding misspelled. paddign: 0; ==> padding: 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the padding misspelling (invalid CSS), those other browsers calculate the cell heights differently.  In IE, the height is added to the padding.

**Change this:**

```
  .top_menu {
      background-image: url(images/header.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 155px;
      font-family: LilyUPC;
      padding-left: 184px;
      padding-top: 120px;
  }
```

**To this:**

```
  .top_menu {
      background-image: url(images/header.png);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      font-family: LilyUPC;
      padding: 120px 0 1em 184px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This makes things much better, but there is still some space between the table elements, just where the borders are supposed to be, but I have already set for the table in an inline style="border-style: hidden;" - isn't it supposed to remove any space between the elements, just like in Firefox?

Comment: No versions of Internet Explorer (including IE8) support the property values "inherit" or "hidden" for `border-style`. Use "none".  For other issues, use a reset (EG: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css) and *validate your CSS*.